# How to select all values from one threshold to another?

Tags: python, tuples

I have an ordered tuple of data:

```
my_data = (1,2,3,2,4,2,3,3,5,7,5,3,6,8,7)
```

How can I subset the tuple items such that all items including and after the first instance of 3 are kept until the first value == 7? For example, the result should be:

```
desired_output = (3,2,4,2,3,3,5,7)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what you mean by threshold (value == 7, or any value >= 7), but here is a solution:

```
my_data = (1,2,3,2,4,2,3,3,5,7,5,3,6,8,7)
index1 = my_data.index(3)
index2 = my_data.index(7)
desired_output = my_data[index1:index2+1]
print desired_output
```

Comment: I've clarified the question based on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

my_data.index(my_data.index(min_thre):my_data.index(max_thre)+1)

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` has `dropwhile` and `takewhile` that you can use to your advantage. Use `dropwhile` to drop everything until the first `3`, and `takewhile` to take everything until the first 7 thereafter. Then just merge the two

```
import itertools

L = [1,2,3,2,4,2,3,3,5,7,5,3,6,8,7]
answer = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x!=7, itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x!=3, L)))
answer.append(7)

In [49]: answer
Out[49]: [3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: `desired_output` is required to be a tuple not a list

Comment: @MichaelMaggs: then use `tuple(...)` to turn that list into a tuple

Answer (score 0):

```
found_three = False
res = []
for d in data:
    if d == 3:
         found_three = True
    if found_three:
         res.append(d)
    if d == 7;
         break
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.